# I can't run modern versions of blender

Tags: installation

I want to use blender to make 3D models for either roblox animations, or just use for building things, it's obvious to me that my laptop can't run the modern versions, but the older ones run fine, smooth in fact, so I was wondering, is there a way to change the rendering mode without having to launch blender? (P.S.No I can't buy better components for my laptop, nor even a whole new pc.)